# Parse data and order alphabetically under letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is what I would like to become:

[image]

This is my javascript:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('exhibitor');

    // CALL FUNCTION
    parsePerObject(JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

    function parsePerObject(data){

    }
```

This is my object in my localStorage :

> {"41873":{"id":"41873","external_id":"","eventid":"5588","venueid":"0","exhibitorcategoryid":"0","name":"Niels
>   Vroman","shortname":"","booth":"","imageurl":"","mapid":"0","y1":"0","x1":"0","x2":"0","y2":"0","description":"Niels
>   uit Zulte.","tel":"0497841121","address":"Drogenboomstraat
>   54","email":"vroman.niels@hotmail.com","web":"http://nielsvroman.be","code":"","username":"","password":"","image1":"","imagedescription1":"","image2":"","imagedescription2":"","image3":"","imagedescription3":"","image4":"","imagedescription4":"","image5":"","imagedescription5":"","image6":"","imagedescription6":"","image7":"","imagedescription7":"","image8":"","imagedescription8":"","image9":"","imagedescription9":"","image10":"","imagedescription10":"","image11":"","imagedescription11":"","image12":"","imagedescription12":"","image13":"","imagedescription13":"","image14":"","imagedescription14":"","image15":"","imagedescription15":"","image16":"","imagedescription16":"","image17":"","imagedescription17":"","image18":"","imagedescription18":"","image19":"","imagedescription19":"","image20":"","imagedescription20":"","order":"0","brands":[],"categories":[],"linktodetails":true,"imagethumb":""},"41877":{"id":"41877","external_id":"","eventid":"5588","venueid":"0","exhibitorcategoryid":"0","name":"Ferdau
>   Daems","shortname":"","booth":"","imageurl":"","mapid":"0","y1":"0","x1":"0","x2":"0","y2":"0","description":"Ferdau
>   Daems","tel":"0497683697","address":"Waregem","email":"fer.dau@gmail.com","web":"http://ferdau.be","code":"","username":"","password":"","image1":"","imagedescription1":"","image2":"","imagedescription2":"","image3":"","imagedescription3":"","image4":"","imagedescription4":"","image5":"","imagedescription5":"","image6":"","imagedescription6":"","image7":"","imagedescription7":"","image8":"","imagedescription8":"","image9":"","imagedescription9":"","image10":"","imagedescription10":"","image11":"","imagedescription11":"","image12":"","imagedescription12":"","image13":"","imagedescription13":"","image14":"","imagedescription14":"","image15":"","imagedescription15":"","image16":"","imagedescription16":"","image17":"","imagedescription17":"","image18":"","imagedescription18":"","image19":"","imagedescription19":"","image20":"","imagedescription20":"","order":"0","brands":[],"categories":[],"linktodetails":true}}

Does anyone know how I can sort alphabetically on the name and make a header from the first letter?

Comment: Objects don't have order. You should use arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an `Array` of objects, not an `Object` of objects, to enable indexing and sorting. Objects don't have order.

You retrieve it from `localStorage`. You parse it.

```
var people = JSON.parse(localStoarge.getItem("exhibitor");
// now you have an array of objects, each object representing a person.
// regardless of what structure you have now, change it to achieve this.
var comparePersons = function(a, b) {
    // this function will compare two people objects.
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    // it's using String.prototype.localeCompare which returns 1 if a.name > b.name,
    // 0 for equal and -1 for smaller. localeCompare is lexicographic comparison.
};
people.sort(comparePersons);
// now you have the people sorted alphabetically.
```

You can run through the people array, get the unique start letters, make an array of out them, and then display data as you want. It should be fairly simple.

```
var letters = '', groups = {};
for (var i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i++) {
     var letterKey = people[i].name.charAt(0).toLowerCase();// get the first letter
     if (letters.indexOf(letterKey)) == -1) {
         letters += letterKey;
         groups[letterKey] = [people[i]];// index the people by unique letters.
     } else {
         groups[letterKey].push([people[i]]);// add to the existing list. Another Syntax fix
     };
};
```

At this point you have an object like this:

```
a: [person1, person2, person5, etc..]//the people at A.
b: [person 3, person 4, etc..]// the people at B.
```

Just use the above data to create the display. Anything more and I would have to invoice you:).

The tricks here are `Array.prototype.sort`([here is more on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) and `String.prototype.localeCompare`([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)).