# How to convert Array to <ul><li> Alphabetical List with Letters as Headings

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel-xdk, appframework

I have an Array ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"]

How do i convert it to the below list.

```
<ul>

<li id = "header">A</li>
<li id = "list" >Apple</li>

<li id = "header">O</li>
<li id = "list" >Orange</li>

<li id = "header">P</li>
<li id = "list" >Pineapple</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: How have ***YOU*** tried to solve that? Show us something we can add to or correct ... please..

Comment: I tried this accepted answer, it shows an error and i am not too good in Javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188556/parse-data-and-order-alphabetically-under-letter

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==

Comment: You're going to have to learn to solve these simple challenges for yourself at some point. Why not start now? Either that, or hire someone.

Comment: Yes, i did try. Will try to imporve my JS knowledge.

Comment: A demo of what you have so far would be helpful.

Comment: I'd use a `<dl>` with `<dt>` and `<dd>` instead. Seems more appropriate. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one of the way you can do it hope this will help you

```js
var arr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"];
var $el = '<ul>';
$.each(arr, function(i, v) {
  $el += '<li id = "header">' + v.slice(0, 1) + '</li>';
  $el += '<li id = "list" >' + v + '</li>';
});
$el += '<ul>';
$('body').append($el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. Only issue is that when the array has multiple items starting with the same Letter. O - Orange1 - O - Orange2. Instead O - Orange1 - Orange

Comment: then tick the answer that meet your query

Comment: If possible do add the above feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = ["Apple", "Another-fruit", "Orange", "Pineapple"];

function createList() {
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    var listItem;
    var currentLetter = '';

    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
        var item = array[i];
        var firstLetter = item.charAt(0);

        if (currentLetter != firstLetter) {
            currentLetter = firstLetter;

            listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.innerHTML = firstLetter;

            list.appendChild(listItem);
        }

        listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.innerHTML = item;

        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    return list;
}

document.body.appendChild(createList());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/edyLg9ga/4/

Comment: Note that `.innerText` won't work in Firefox. Use `.textContent` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/edyLg9ga/3/

Comment: This answer works well but i accepted the above answer due to the shorter code. Thank you.

Comment: The above answer is shorter because it doesn't work, by the way. If more than one word with the same letter appears in the list, it will add multiple headers. Reconsider your choice. ;)